# JavaScript pause setInterval on mouseover

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a script that cycles through an array of strings and displays them on a specific class using innerHTML.

The arrays setup looks something like:

```
var myArray = [
  "TextString1",
  "TextString2",
  "TextString3",
  "TextString4"
]

var AnotherArray = [
  "AnotherArray1",
  "AnotherArray2",
  "AnotherArray3",
  "AnotherArray4"
]
```

And the SetInterval function itself looks like this

```
  function ArrayPlusDelay(array, delegate, delay) {
    var i = 0
     // seed first call and store interval (to clear later)
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
            // each loop, call passed in function
          delegate(array[i]);
            // increment, and if we're past array, clear interval
          if(i++ >= array.length - 1) {
            i = 0 //clearInterval(interval);
          }
      }, delay)
    return interval
  }

  ArrayPlusDelay(myArray, function(obj) {
    document.querySelector('.cycle_questions').innerHTML = obj
  },2000)

  ArrayPlusDelay(AnotherArray, function(obj) {
    document.querySelector('.cycle_research').innerHTML = obj
  },2000)
```

Where do I inject the AddEventListener to make the looping stop? And on mouseleave make make the loop continue?

Thanks!

Comment: You've got lots of options for how to do this. Depending on how precise you want to be with the timing, one simple option would be to set some variable on mouseenter and clear it on mouseleave, and check the status of the variable inside your interval handler

Comment: Hi @Hamms, thanks for getting back to this problem. I tried setting a variable on mouseenter. I managed to get it to stop using something like. if(isPaused) { // clearInterval(interval) } But I wasnt able to get it to run again on mouseleave. Any pointers?

Comment: can you tell us the precision desired? I mean, for simple solution and for a delay for 2000ms, the next interval could be 3999ms(If you go in your element after 1999ms then when you go out the next interval will be execute 2sec later). Is this acceptable?

Comment: Precision is not a priority if there is a way to write cleaner/re-useable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.Here i've introduced two different array.For the purpose of segregation you need two separate interval object.First is **`intervalObjOne`** and second is **`intervalObjTwo`**.Two object for two different array.If want to use a third array create a third one.You can even make it dynamic,but for the purpose of simplicity i kept them static.

**`domSelectorByClass`** and **`domSelectorByQuery`** is just a shorter version for **`document.GetElemensByClassName`** and **`document.querySelector`** to keep the codebase clean.

then the **`intervalArr`** is introduced which contain both **`intervalObjOne`** and **`intervalObjTwo`**.

Then run a **`forEach`** loop to iterate over the **`intervalArr`** and call **`attachInterval`**,**`addMouseLeaveEvent`** and **`addMouseOverEvent`** functions and pass respective intervalObj to each of them as parameter.

**`attachInterval`** event will initiate a **`setInterval`** on respective intervalObj's interval property.

**`addMouseLeaveEvent`** function will attach a **`mouseleave`** event on the respective div element.

**`addMouseOverEvent`** function will attach a **`mouseover`** event on respective div which will call **`clearInterval`** to stop the **`setInterval`**.

```js
var myArray = ["TextString1","TextString2","TextString3","TextString4"]
var anotherArray = ["TextString5","TextString6"]

var intervalObjOne = {array: myArray,interval : 'undefined',tick:0,className:'cycle_questions'}    
var intervalObjTwo = {array: anotherArray,interval: 'undefined',tick:0,className:'cycle_research'}

var domSelectorByClass = document.getElementsByClassName.bind(document)
var domSelectorByQuery = document.querySelector.bind(document)

var intervalArr = [intervalObjOne,intervalObjTwo]

function ArrayPlusDelay(delegate, delay,intervalObj) {

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
             delegate(intervalObj.array[intervalObj.tick])
                    if(intervalObj.tick++ >= (intervalObj.array).length - 1) {
                 intervalObj.tick=0
                    }
                   }, delay)
  
  return interval
}

intervalArr.forEach(function(elem,index){
  attachInterval(elem)
  addMouseLeaveEvent(elem)
  addMouseOverEvent(elem)
})

function attachInterval(intervalObj){
  intervalObj.interval =  ArrayPlusDelay(function(obj) {
  domSelectorByQuery('.'+intervalObj.className).innerHTML = obj
  },2000,intervalObj)
}

function addMouseOverEvent(intervalObj){
    domSelectorByClass(intervalObj.className)[0].addEventListener('mouseover',function(event){
    clearInterval(intervalObj.interval);    
 });  
}

function addMouseLeaveEvent(intervalObj){
    domSelectorByClass(intervalObj.className)[0].addEventListener('mouseleave',function(event){
        attachInterval(intervalObj)
    }); 
}
```

```html
<div class='cycle_questions' style='display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;width:100px;height:40px;'></div>
<div class='cycle_research' style='display:inline-block;border:1px solid green;width:100px;height:40px;'></div>
```

Comment: that cant not work on multiple call of ArrayPlusDelay for different array and use

Comment: Hi @Al-zami, thanks for looking into this issue! Thats a clever solution! Sorry if I wasnt clear enough, I currently have multiple of these "text-slideshows" does your script cover that scenario? Thank you! I've edited the questions to reflect multiple arrays

Comment: @SebastianGraz checkout the more optimized solution

Comment: Thanks for the updated solution, I like how reusable it is. I had to add 'var' to interval but otherwise it worked as expected!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is:
 1. having an object which store your state
 2. Generate a scope to store the position of `i`:

I slighly modified your code to have something easyer to test:

```
var myArray = [
  "TextString1",
  "TextString2",
  "TextString3",
  "TextString4"
];

var myArrayFoo = [
  "TFoong1",
  "TFoong2",
  "TFoong3",
  "TFoong4"
]
// Used to generate your scope
var myFnGenerator = function(array, delegate, interval) {
  var i = 0;
  return function() {
    if (interval.stop) {
      return false;
    }
      delegate(array[i]);
      if(i++ >= array.length - 1) {
       i=0

      }
  };

}
function ArrayPlusDelay(array, delegate, delay) {
  // The object which store your state
  var interval = {
    stop: true
  };
  var fn = myFnGenerator(array, delegate, interval);
  interval.timeout = setInterval(fn, delay);
  interval.stop = false;
  return interval;
}

var interval = ArrayPlusDelay(myArray, function(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
},2000)

var intervalFoo = ArrayPlusDelay(myArrayFoo, function(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
},2000)

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(event){
   interval.stop = true;
});
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('mouseout',function(event){
   interval.stop = false;
});


document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(event){
   intervalFoo.stop = true;
});
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('mouseout',function(event){
   intervalFoo.stop = false;
});
```

I think this way is easyer to read than clearTimeout then relaunch it inside `mouseout` (less copy paste), but I guess it is more a code's style. If you prefer having clearTimeout:

```
var myArray = [
  "TextString1",
  "TextString2",
  "TextString3",
  "TextString4"
];

var myArrayFoo = [
  "TFoong1",
  "TFoong2",
  "TFoong3",
  "TFoong4"
]
var myFnGenerator = function(array, delegate) {
  var i = 0;
  return function() {
      delegate(array[i]);
      if(i++ >= array.length - 1) {
       i=0

      }
  };
}
function launchInterval(interval, delay) {
   if (interval.timeout === null) {
     interval.timeout = setInterval(interval.fn, delay);
  }
}
function clearMyInterval(interval) {
  if (interval.timeout !== null) 
     clearInterval(interval.timeout);
  interval.timeout = null;
}
function ArrayPlusDelay(array, delegate, delay) {
  var interval = {
    timeout: null
  };
  var fn = myFnGenerator(array, delegate);
  interval.fn = fn;
  launchInterval(interval, delay);
  return interval;
}

var interval = ArrayPlusDelay(myArray, function(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
},2000)

var intervalFoo = ArrayPlusDelay(myArrayFoo, function(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
},2000)

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(event){
  clearMyInterval(interval);
});
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('mouseout',function(event){
   launchInterval(interval, 2000);
});

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(event){
  clearMyInterval(intervalFoo);
});
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('mouseout',function(event){
   launchInterval(intervalFoo, 2000);
});
```

Must meet your needs. I let interval accessible from the function of your setInterval to be able to use `clearInterval` inside the callback.

Comment: You could store `delay` in `interval` then reuse it in `launchInterval`